# Is it possible to write a program in C that does nothing - not even taking up memory?

Tags: c

This is a tricky C question asked in interview: Write a program that does nothing, not even taking up memory.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Define exactly what you mean by take memory? Does it imply that the program cannot even allocate any memory to the Call Stack and/or Heap or use any memory at all when run?

Comment: @mr_eclair: Include the interview tag if it is an interview question.

Comment: avoid that employer. They haven't a clue what they're asking.

Comment: @mr_eclair: Create empty *.c file and compile. :)

Comment: @dhinesh: empty file is not a program. Program is supposed to have some code, atleast `main()`.

Comment: @Alex, it may be that they are prompting the interviewee to say "This is not possible, the address-space, stack etc are already allocated.".  Perhaps they are trying to find out whether you *know* that once `main` is invoked, memory has already been allocated.  Not defending them, this is just an assumption based on trick questions I've had in the past.

Comment: In my experience, such questions are hardly useful in an interview. If interviewer wants to establish a knowledge baseline, he better ask "Is it possible to do that?". Tricky questions are generally misinterpreted and could eliminate good candidates. If he wants the candidate to ask questions before giving a definitive answer, he better have a conversation instead of applying a written test.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All programs use memory.  When you run the program, the OS will set up an address space for the program, copy its arguments into its process space, give it a process ID and a thread, give it some file descriptors for I/O, etc.  Even if your program immediately terminates you still use up this memory and CPU time.

Answer (score 4):

No its not possible.  The code and stack must go somewhere and that will, nearly always, be in memory.

Ignoring that surely its pretty easy to just write an application that exits straight away.

Comment: "nearly always"? Where else would the code and stack go but in memory?

Comment: @Martin:  Some machines have "code memory" and "stack memory".  I guess its still memory .. .but its not memory in the malloc sense of the term as it comes from a totally different pool.

Answer (score 2):

your response should be along the lines of enquiring as to 'why' you'd want to do such a thing. this would show a latitude for thinking beyond the question.

Comment: And if his lecturers are anything like mine were ... they'll fail him for being a smart arse.  So glad I left university (Well glad i left the learning side of it ... the partying and sleeping all day side was rather enjoyable ;)).

Comment: i'll drink to that... zzzz!! :-)

Comment: I actually think that ask why do you want to do it is not a great question in this case. It's an artificial or hypothetical question exploring some important concepts - the null program itself doesn't need to be valuable if the thought in trying to produce it teaches something. Sometimes the journey is its own reward.

Comment: dj - as part of a wider discussion, i think the reason should be asked, otherwise it's a blind investigation. in the real world, it's akin to being asked to illegally cross the road avoiding white cars. if you don't ask the question(s), you'll not realise that the white cars in question are police cars and that 'other' white cars have no significance on the request (awful example, but you see my point hopefully - or not!!). :-)

Comment: @Goz - lecturers? This is for a job interview. And a company that fails a candidate for trying to make something useful out of an interview question this bad, is a company that deserves the horribly unskilled employees they end up with (because everyone competent will be glad to go somewhere else).

Answer (score 1):

On the surface the question seems to have a simple answer: "No, it can't be done." @templatetypedef has given some reasons.

But perhaps the point of the question is to see how you address it. You might get "marks" for asking "what kind of memory" or for observing some of the points that @templatetypedef made. Or for showing the empty main() method given by @Mihran Hovsepyan and then explaining that some memory will be involved even in this minimal case.

Answer (score 1):

Although there will be some memory allocated by OS when you launch a program, most people don't know that main() is not the real program entry point. mainCRTStartup is, at least on Windows console app. If you create a program with real entry point you will avoid heap initialization routines, command argument parsing, global variable initialization and so on.

So, in some sense, you can make a program that avoids heap management and stuff. But OS will still read it into memory.

See: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/minexe

Answer (score 0):

Empty program is a program, isn't it?

Below is my no resource use program :)

---

Also note that. Strictly speaking, a program really don't consume any resource until OS load it and make it run. When this happen we call it a Process.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that it's implementation-specific. An implementation could support null programs and the `execve` (or equivalent) mechanism could perform the equivalent of `_Exit(0)` when it encounters one, but in practice it doesn't.